# IE automation, automated login to a particular page

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, ie-automation

I am trying to automate login to a page through Internet Explorer with VBA code,
 however, I am stuck as I am not able to identify the login and password fields,
 as they do not have any ID or Tag name. Is there any way to use xPath or some other alternatives to solve this problem? Please see the login page screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjJeS.png

xPath looks like this:

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/input
```

Here is the html code of the page:

```html
<div id="root">
         <div class="root__content">
            <div class="header1__wrap">
               <header class="header1"><a class="header1__logo" href="https://"></a></header>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
               <div class="content__main">
                  <div>
                     <div style="padding: 0px 10px;"></div>
                     <div class="grid">
                        <div class="gridone">
                           <div class="form" name="web/log_in">
                              <div class="form__title">Log In</div>
                              <div class="section">
                                 <div class="section__top"></div>
                                 <div class="section__content">
                                    <p class="link" name="sign_up_link"><a href="/sign_up">Register</a></p>
                                    <div class="edit selected" name="email">
                                       <div class="edit__icon">
                                          <i class="svg-icon">
                                             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 612.011 612.011" width="50" height="44" version="1.1">
                                             </svg>
                                          </i>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="edit__field">
                                          <div class="edit__label selected">Login/Email address</div>
                                          <input tabindex="0" type="text" value="" autoComplete="off">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="edit" name="password">
                                       <div class="edit__icon">
                                          <i class="svg-icon">
                                             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 42" width="40px" height="42px" version="1.1">
                                             </svg>
                                          </i>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="edit__field">
                                          <div class="edit__label">Password</div>
                                          <div style="display: none;"><input type="text"><input type="password"></div>
                                          <input tabindex="0" type="password" value="" autoComplete="off">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="edit__pass">SHOW</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="button link right" data-type="link" name="forgot"><span>Forgot password?</span></p>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="section__bottom">
                                    <div class="button submit" data-type="submit" name="button_submit">
                                       <div>Login</div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why not set use the 'input' tag, then loop through them and find that particular element?

Comment: Use F12 -Network tab.

Comment: Maybe you could try to identify those 2 elements by the tag input and property type using the method GetAttribute. [More Info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTMLElement ID is not a requirement for grabbing your elements. In your case, your username field has a class name `edit__label selected` and your password can be found by the element name `password`.

See if this works for you:

```
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = ieobj.document

Dim oUser As Object, oPass As Object
Set oUser = doc.getElementsByClassName("edit__label selected")(0)
Set oPass = doc.getElementsByName("password")(0)

'.Value may or may not work. Try both
oUser.Value = "myUserName"
oUser.innerText = "myUserName"

'.Value may or may not work. Try both
oPass.Value = "pa$$word"
oPass.innerText = "pa$$word"
```

Comment: Thank you K.Dᴀᴠɪs, you got me on the right track!
However, I am having some difficulties filling in password. Here is my code:

`doc.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).innerText = "sdfsdfsd@sdfdsf.com"

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

doc.getElementsByName("password")(0).Value = "Testing-789"`

I put the waiting command, thought that it would help, but the password field remains empty. Not sure why. Any ideas?
Also I tried to use "input"(1) instead "password"(0), but got the same result.

Comment: Fixed it, it seems that there were more "input" tags in the code of the web page, I just needed to change the number in the brackets.
Thank you again, K.Dᴀᴠɪs!